# Bind colection to ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have basic problem with WPF, I tried setting `DataContext`, binding to collection and somehow I still cannot get it to work. I searched way to long for such basic problem... I must be missing something very simple. I appreciate any help :)

Code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Photo> MyPhotos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
public DataTemplate()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  listBox.DataContext = MyPhotos;
  MyPhotos.Add(new Photo(@"path to existing file"));
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Photo}">
    <Border Margin="3">
      <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPhotos}" Background="Silver" Width="600" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Photo class:

```
public class Photo
{
  public string Source { get; set; }
  public Photo(string path)
  {
    Source = path;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368506/wpf-listbox-binding

Comment: What is `Photo` class? Share details. You are missing property binding. You need to implemented datatemplate

Comment: @GaurangDave Updated question :)

Comment: @jsanalytics Added this to code, doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference `DataTemplate` as `ItemTemplate` into your `ListBox`. Define `Key` into your `DataTemplate`.

```
<Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Photo}">
        <Border Margin="3">
          <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPhotos}" Background="Silver" Width="600" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Change your DataContext to `this`.

```
listBox.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: @MichałTurczyn check update in my answer. Your DataContext is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. MyPhotos have to be a **Property** {get; set} functions, NOT a **Field**

   > `public ObservableCollection<Photo> MyPhotos { get; set; }`
2. Code behind:

   > `DataContext = this`
   >
   > **NOT** `listBox.DataContext = MyPhotos`
3. XAML: Add DisplayMemberPath to show data

   > DisplayMemberPath="Source"